# How to open a specific quantity of webpages at preset intervals in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, window.open

I'm relatively new to JavaScript. I would like to have a user click a button, opening a specific webpage (or video in this case) every 3 seconds, for 20 pages. I can't seem to figure out how to do that with any kind of loop without either looping the window.open() (effectively crashing my browser) or causing the webpage to not load at all due to another loop OR causing all the tabs to open at once. Here's what I have so far for JS:

```
var numberOfVids = 20;
var vidNumber = 1;
var website = "http://example.com";
var myVar;

function executeVidBot() {
     myVar = setInterval(openVid, 3000);
}

function openVid() {
     window.open(website);
     vidNumber++;
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to execute the VidBot.</p>

<button onclick="executeVidBot()">Execute VidBot</button>

<script src="vidbot.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated as I've been looking for a solution for a while and can't seem to find one.

Comment: To clarify the question, when the user clicks on a button you want to launch 20 popups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using setInterval is the correct way of executing code at regular intervals, however you will need to manually stop the interval when it has reached the limit in your openVid() function:

```
function openVid() {
    window.open(website);
    vidNumber++;
    if (vidNumber == numberOfVids) {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
}
```

The first function call won't execute for 3 seconds however. You can manually call it to execute immediately.

```
function executeVidBot() {
    openVid(); // Execute now
    myVar = setInterval(openVid, 3000); // Execute in 3 seconds
}
```

If you wanted to use a for loop you would need to use setTimeout instead which executes just once:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfVids; i++) {
    setTimeout(openVid, 3000 * i);
}
```

Most browsers will block multiple window.open calls due to the potential for abuse. Chrome for example blocks them and displays the message "the following pop-ups were blocked from this page". If you are trying to do something that's likely to annoy the user I would suggest that you don't.

If you're doing something else like a testing task where you need to open a page 20 times it might be better to use a headless browser like [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/) to automate the task, i.e load the page and click a button 20 times or just load the page directly 20 times.

Comment: Thank you. That is extremely helpful.